# designing a variable gain amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, variable

I want to build a variable gain amplifier.  My first thought was to build two feedback resistors and switch one or the other off with a MOSFET.  However, the MOSFETs have shunt diodes which are going to interfere.

There are thousands of MOSFETs on Avnet for example, and randomly selecting I see only models with the built-in shunt diodes.  Hoping someone can identify a keyword to pinpoint MOSFETs without diodes, or identify a different design that is better that what I am proposing.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't bother using MOSFETs. Instead, use FET-based devices such as the CD4066.

Furthermore, if you only need 2 gain settings, you only need 1 switch. As an example

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZKnN8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

will give a gain of 10 or 100. (Note that your example, if it worked, would give gains of 11 or 101). Also note that, whenever possible, put your switch elements to ground rather than floating, since that way the gate voltages will not vary with signal.

Comment: Can't you also get any gain in between by having the FET partially on?

Comment: @RobertStiffler :  The CD4066 suggested by WhatRoughBeast works as a switch (either On or Off). The 4066 is generally used as a switch to pass analog signals. So with 4066 you can't get "partially" on.

Comment: @RobertStiffler - You can, but it's not practical. First, the exact resistance you get will be extremely sensitive to noise. Second the resistance will not be constant for a given voltage if the temperature changes.

Comment: Make sure the 4066 is run at a decent supply voltage - at 5V it's pretty crap re on-resistance and \$\Delta\$ on-resistance. Even on higher voltages you might see a fair bit of distortion at high gains with J1 "on".

Answer (score 1):

> I want to build a variable gain amplifier.

I've had really great success building one using the AD5207 digipot: -

[image]

It's controllable by its serial port (SDI and CLK) and there are two in a package. If you need more channels you can cascade several devices together.

I've had them wired around an op-amp to produce gains from unity to 16 with quite decent resolution. I could have mustered more gain but the frequency response starts to droop above gains of 16 at 50 kHz (that was the spec). I found them to be pretty clean noise wise and generally performed well. Gain drift with temperature (1 to 16) was excellant but I would expect gains of 32 or higher to be less precise.

This was the configuration I used: -

[image]

Comment: I may need bigger gains in this case, but this is really cool and something I didn't even know existed, so thanks!

Comment: You can produce bigger gains but you have to be aware of high ratios and temperature effects. Also, as you produce bigger gains, the control you have over the ratio of feedback resistance to grounding resistance is much grainier.

Comment: I use the ADI digipots. I had a very successful high gain amp by putting a 10k part in series with a 1k part to maintain good control at higher gains.

Comment: @PeterSmith I was quite a bit concerned about the ratiometric temperature coefficient and I felt that one device would be better than two in this respect (zero to +80C was the target environment!).

Comment: My specific application allowed me to auto-calibrate so it was not as much of a  concern, but the ratiometric effects can certainly be cause for concern.